# CSS: Setting vertically in middle

Tags: html, css

Consider following:

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="left"></div>
    <div class="right"></div>
</div>
```

Left div has less height than the right div. Can I set the left div vertically in the middle of the right div?  I can not set the margin-top because the height varies.

[image]

Here's the jsfiddle link: 
http://jsfiddle.net/k8972/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hi now used to `display inline-block` and give to `vertical-align`  and remove to `float`

as like this

```
.wrap{
    overflow:hidden;
    border:1px solid red;
    width:250px;
    display:table;
}


.left{
    width:100px;
    height:50px;
    background:yellow;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle;
}

.right{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background:brown;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

live demo http://jsfiddle.net/k8972/2/

Answer (score 1):

You can use display: table-cell and vertical-align: middle; but it won't work on IE7 or less.

Comment: Sorry, it's middle, not centre.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of methods mentioned here

http://phrogz.net/css/vertical-align/index.html